# Sort bar chart descending by value

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js, bar-chart

I'm having trouble getting this bar chart to sort with the length of the bars in descending order, and to scale the x-axis properly with the domain. I hardcoded the domain based on the highest count value. The count doesn't need to aggregate because there is only one row per state per year. For the domain, I tried:

```
.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
            return d.count;
        })])
```

But it didn't work property, but worked on most of my other charts.

Here's the code for the chart:

```
     var barRegion = "West";

     var y = d3.scaleBand()
                .range([h, 0])
                .padding(0.1);

      var x = d3.scaleLinear()
                .range([0, w]);

      var svg1 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      x.domain([0, 1500]) // NEED DYNAMIC
      y.domain(dataset.map(function(d) {
        //console.log(barRegion)
        //console.log(d)
        if(d.region === barRegion && d.year === "2011"){
          return d.state;
        }
     }));


  // append the rectangles for the bar chart
  svg1.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("width", function(d) {
                        if(d.region === barRegion && d.year === "2011"){
                          //console.log(d.count)

          return x(d.count); 
        }

      } )
      .attr("y", function(d) {
                if(d.region === barRegion && d.year === "2012"){
          return y(d.state); 
        }

      // return y(d.state); 
     })
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth());

  // add the x Axis
  svg1.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // add the y Axis
  svg1.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

the data is read in like this:

```
      d3.csv("data.csv").then(function(dataset){


      dataset.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseTime(d.year);
        d.region = d['region'];
        d.state = d['state'];
        d.count = d['count'];
        //console.log(d)
      });
```

data.csv

```
state,region,year,count
Alabama,South,2010,1
Alabama,South,2011,1
Alabama,South,2012,0
Alabama,South,2013,0
Alabama,South,2014,2
Alabama,South,2015,6
Alaska,West,2010,2245
Alaska,West,2011,1409
Alaska,West,2012,1166
Alaska,West,2013,1329
Alaska,West,2014,1296
Alaska,West,2015,1575
Arizona,West,2010,6
Arizona,West,2011,7
Arizona,West,2012,4
Arizona,West,2013,3
Arizona,West,2014,31
Arizona,West,2015,10
Arkansas,South,2010,15
Arkansas,South,2011,44
Arkansas,South,2012,4
Arkansas,South,2013,4
Arkansas,South,2014,1
Arkansas,South,2015,0
California,West,2010,546
California,West,2011,195
California,West,2012,243
California,West,2013,240
California,West,2014,191
California,West,2015,130
Colorado,West,2010,4
Colorado,West,2011,23
Colorado,West,2012,7
Colorado,West,2013,2
Colorado,West,2014,13
Colorado,West,2015,7
Connecticut,Northeast,2010,0
Connecticut,Northeast,2011,0
Connecticut,Northeast,2012,0
Connecticut,Northeast,2013,0
Connecticut,Northeast,2014,0
Connecticut,Northeast,2015,1
Delaware,South,2010,0
Delaware,South,2011,0
Delaware,South,2012,0
Delaware,South,2013,0
Delaware,South,2014,0
Delaware,South,2015,0
Florida,South,2010,0
Florida,South,2011,0
Florida,South,2012,0
Florida,South,2013,0
Florida,South,2014,0
Florida,South,2015,0
Georgia,South,2010,0
Georgia,South,2011,0
Georgia,South,2012,0
Georgia,South,2013,0
Georgia,South,2014,0
Georgia,South,2015,0
Hawaii,West,2010,17
Hawaii,West,2011,34
Hawaii,West,2012,40
Hawaii,West,2013,30
Hawaii,West,2014,26
Hawaii,West,2015,53
Idaho,West,2010,7
Idaho,West,2011,4
Idaho,West,2012,4
Idaho,West,2013,11
Idaho,West,2014,31
Idaho,West,2015,38
Illinois,Midwest,2010,1
Illinois,Midwest,2011,0
Illinois,Midwest,2012,2
Illinois,Midwest,2013,1
Illinois,Midwest,2014,0
Illinois,Midwest,2015,1
Indiana,Midwest,2010,1
Indiana,Midwest,2011,0
Indiana,Midwest,2012,3
Indiana,Midwest,2013,0
Indiana,Midwest,2014,0
Indiana,Midwest,2015,0
Iowa,Midwest,2010,0
Iowa,Midwest,2011,0
Iowa,Midwest,2012,0
Iowa,Midwest,2013,0
Iowa,Midwest,2014,0
Iowa,Midwest,2015,0
Kansas,Midwest,2010,0
Kansas,Midwest,2011,0
Kansas,Midwest,2012,0
Kansas,Midwest,2013,2
Kansas,Midwest,2014,42
Kansas,Midwest,2015,60
Kentucky,South,2010,0
Kentucky,South,2011,0
Kentucky,South,2012,2
Kentucky,South,2013,0
Kentucky,South,2014,0
Kentucky,South,2015,0
Louisiana,South,2010,1
Louisiana,South,2011,0
Louisiana,South,2012,0
Louisiana,South,2013,0
Louisiana,South,2014,0
Louisiana,South,2015,0
Maine,Northeast,2010,1
Maine,Northeast,2011,0
Maine,Northeast,2012,1
Maine,Northeast,2013,1
Maine,Northeast,2014,0
Maine,Northeast,2015,0
Maryland,South,2010,1
Maryland,South,2011,0
Maryland,South,2012,0
Maryland,South,2013,0
Maryland,South,2014,0
Maryland,South,2015,0
Massachusetts,Northeast,2010,0
Massachusetts,Northeast,2011,0
Massachusetts,Northeast,2012,0
Massachusetts,Northeast,2013,0
Massachusetts,Northeast,2014,0
Massachusetts,Northeast,2015,0
Michigan,Midwest,2010,0
Michigan,Midwest,2011,0
Michigan,Midwest,2012,0
Michigan,Midwest,2013,0
Michigan,Midwest,2014,0
Michigan,Midwest,2015,2
Minnesota,Midwest,2010,0
Minnesota,Midwest,2011,0
Minnesota,Midwest,2012,0
Minnesota,Midwest,2013,0
Minnesota,Midwest,2014,1
Minnesota,Midwest,2015,0
Mississippi,South,2010,0
Mississippi,South,2011,0
Mississippi,South,2012,0
Mississippi,South,2013,0
Mississippi,South,2014,0
Mississippi,South,2015,3
Missouri,Midwest,2010,2
Missouri,Midwest,2011,3
Missouri,Midwest,2012,2
Missouri,Midwest,2013,0
Missouri,Midwest,2014,1
Missouri,Midwest,2015,5
Montana,West,2010,7
Montana,West,2011,11
Montana,West,2012,9
Montana,West,2013,14
Montana,West,2014,29
Montana,West,2015,19
Nebraska,Midwest,2010,2
Nebraska,Midwest,2011,0
Nebraska,Midwest,2012,1
Nebraska,Midwest,2013,0
Nebraska,Midwest,2014,0
Nebraska,Midwest,2015,3
Nevada,West,2010,38
Nevada,West,2011,86
Nevada,West,2012,22
Nevada,West,2013,34
Nevada,West,2014,161
Nevada,West,2015,172
New Hampshire,Northeast,2010,1
New Hampshire,Northeast,2011,0
New Hampshire,Northeast,2012,0
New Hampshire,Northeast,2013,0
New Hampshire,Northeast,2014,0
New Hampshire,Northeast,2015,0
New Jersey,Northeast,2010,0
New Jersey,Northeast,2011,0
New Jersey,Northeast,2012,0
New Jersey,Northeast,2013,0
New Jersey,Northeast,2014,0
New Jersey,Northeast,2015,0
New Mexico,West,2010,7
New Mexico,West,2011,7
New Mexico,West,2012,3
New Mexico,West,2013,6
New Mexico,West,2014,3
New Mexico,West,2015,12
New York,Northeast,2010,0
New York,Northeast,2011,1
New York,Northeast,2012,0
New York,Northeast,2013,0
New York,Northeast,2014,0
New York,Northeast,2015,2
North Carolina,South,2010,0
North Carolina,South,2011,0
North Carolina,South,2012,0
North Carolina,South,2013,0
North Carolina,South,2014,1
North Carolina,South,2015,0
North Dakota,Midwest,2010,0
North Dakota,Midwest,2011,0
North Dakota,Midwest,2012,1
North Dakota,Midwest,2013,0
North Dakota,Midwest,2014,0
North Dakota,Midwest,2015,0
Ohio,Midwest,2010,1
Ohio,Midwest,2011,3
Ohio,Midwest,2012,0
Ohio,Midwest,2013,1
Ohio,Midwest,2014,1
Ohio,Midwest,2015,0
Oklahoma,South,2010,41
Oklahoma,South,2011,63
Oklahoma,South,2012,34
Oklahoma,South,2013,103
Oklahoma,South,2014,585
Oklahoma,South,2015,888
Oregon,West,2010,4
Oregon,West,2011,0
Oregon,West,2012,4
Oregon,West,2013,2
Oregon,West,2014,4
Oregon,West,2015,3
Pennsylvania,Northeast,2010,0
Pennsylvania,Northeast,2011,0
Pennsylvania,Northeast,2012,0
Pennsylvania,Northeast,2013,0
Pennsylvania,Northeast,2014,0
Pennsylvania,Northeast,2015,0
Rhode Island,Northeast,2010,0
Rhode Island,Northeast,2011,0
Rhode Island,Northeast,2012,0
Rhode Island,Northeast,2013,0
Rhode Island,Northeast,2014,0
Rhode Island,Northeast,2015,0
South Carolina,South,2010,0
South Carolina,South,2011,0
South Carolina,South,2012,0
South Carolina,South,2013,0
South Carolina,South,2014,3
South Carolina,South,2015,0
South Dakota,Midwest,2010,0
South Dakota,Midwest,2011,3
South Dakota,Midwest,2012,1
South Dakota,Midwest,2013,1
South Dakota,Midwest,2014,1
South Dakota,Midwest,2015,0
Tennessee,South,2010,1
Tennessee,South,2011,0
Tennessee,South,2012,4
Tennessee,South,2013,1
Tennessee,South,2014,1
Tennessee,South,2015,1
Texas,South,2010,9
Texas,South,2011,18
Texas,South,2012,11
Texas,South,2013,16
Texas,South,2014,8
Texas,South,2015,21
Utah,West,2010,17
Utah,West,2011,16
Utah,West,2012,16
Utah,West,2013,6
Utah,West,2014,10
Utah,West,2015,4
Vermont,Northeast,2010,0
Vermont,Northeast,2011,0
Vermont,Northeast,2012,0
Vermont,Northeast,2013,0
Vermont,Northeast,2014,0
Vermont,Northeast,2015,0
Virginia,South,2010,1
Virginia,South,2011,7
Virginia,South,2012,4
Virginia,South,2013,0
Virginia,South,2014,1
Virginia,South,2015,0
Washington,West,2010,5
Washington,West,2011,14
Washington,West,2012,6
Washington,West,2013,18
Washington,West,2014,6
Washington,West,2015,11
West Virginia,South,2010,1
West Virginia,South,2011,0
West Virginia,South,2012,0
West Virginia,South,2013,1
West Virginia,South,2014,0
West Virginia,South,2015,0
Wisconsin,Midwest,2010,0
Wisconsin,Midwest,2011,0
Wisconsin,Midwest,2012,0
Wisconsin,Midwest,2013,0
Wisconsin,Midwest,2014,0
Wisconsin,Midwest,2015,0
Wyoming,West,2010,43
Wyoming,West,2011,6
Wyoming,West,2012,9
Wyoming,West,2013,73
Wyoming,West,2014,179
Wyoming,West,2015,198
```

Answer (score 0):

For sorting the bars, you can sort the selection itself (slower<sup>*</sup>) or you can sort the data array (faster) before joining the data and before calculating the band scale's domain. Since [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts in place, it's just:

```
dataset.sort(function(a, b){
    return b.count - a.count;
})
```

However, pay attention to some facts:

1. This will sort the *entire* array, and you have an categorical y axis where a state can have many years of data. Therefore, filter the data array by the desired year first.
2. Your `forEach` is incorrect, you should coerce the strings to numbers:

   ```
   d.count = +d.count
   ```

   Also, you don't need bracket notation, since you have the property's name.
3. I suggest you remove all those `if` inside the `attr` callbacks. Deal with the filters outside.

By the way, your domain calculation is correct (but it has nothing to do with the order of the bars).

---

<sup>*</sup> Sorting a selection is not only slower than sorting an array, you also cannot use the scale for positioning the elements, requiring another code just to translate everything.

Comment: thanks.  i see that i can sort the dataset as you said. how and where do i filter the array before calculating the band scale's domain? this eventually needs to be part of an interactive viz, which is why i have the filtering in the callbacks. could you point me to some example code? i tried to filter just before calling the domain and it doesn't work. does it need to be inside the y domain?

Comment: My answer deals with the `sort`, I'm not sure what this `filter` you're talking about is. If you are talking about filtering the years, which was just a suggestion, I suggest you create an online version of the code and post it as a new question, with the relevant details.

Comment: thank you! apologies for the confusion. did a retry here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58237911/d3-v5-sort-bar-chart-descending-by-value-with-conditional-data-filter-with-corre